# Software to replace left Shift key by vertical bar or backslash keys

Tags: windows, gratis, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've purchased a physical keyboard that is missing a left key for typing the backslash character or the vertical tab character.

Is there a software to virtualize a key stroke on the <kbd>left Shift</kbd> key so that it functions as such (either <kbd>|</kbd> or <kbd>\</kbd> based on the <kbd>right Shift</kbd> key)?

- **Operating system**: Windows 11
- **Availability**: Free
- **Flexibility**: Toggle on or off manually.

Comment: For which system? Under what conditions - all the time?

Comment: @Destroy666 It is for Windows 11 and free. I'd manually toggle the software on or off...

Answer (score 1):

Any kind of remapping can be done with very popular [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) software.

In your case this simple script should work:

```
LShift::\
```

Save it as `anything.ahk` and run it. Check more info about [mapping](https://documentation.help/AutoHotKey-Functions/Remap.htm) and [keys](https://documentation.help/AutoHotkey-en/KeyList.htm).